# Searches with different nodejs parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an application and I need to do a search of some parameters, mandatory and others not.
With parameters not mandatory.

I need the indifferent search of whether the two parameters are not mandatory or not.
or there is only one of the two mandatory.

```
var find = Teacher.find({
      'user': {
        "$in": onlines_clean
      },
      'teacher_del': true,
      'language': language,
      skill: {
        $in: [category]
      },
      'hour.hour_time': hora,
      $and: [{
        "hour.pricea": {
          $lte: price
        }
      }, {
        "hour.priceb": {
          $gte: price
        }
      }]
    })
  }
```

So far, so good 
the problem comes when I want to add two more parameters that are not mandatory

```
      expression: {
        $in: [speak]
      },
      'native': native
```

with

```
     var native= native;
      if (req.params.native) {
     native= req.params.native;
  }
```

with

```
 conditions if - else
```

neither of these ways works for me, since the route forces me to follow this rule

```
/add/exit/:language/:category/:hora/:price/:native?/:speak?
```

I must pass the native parameter, and then speak,
I can't ignore the native parameter

with req.query  the same thing

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would change the route to use GET query parameters instead, since these have no ordering and can be left out without causing this issue.

If you cannot change how the path looks like, I suggest having a special value that represents no value, like “null”:

```
/add/exit/:language/:category/:hora/:price/null/:speak?
```

This way you would look for these values in your `if - else` statements to decide what to do.